# Appending List Items and Printing the Entire List

Tags: python, list, append, jython

I have simplified the code I am working on, to identify the problem. I have looked at other questions, textbooks and python.org, but am missing some basic concept.

```
def array_():

  i=0
  while i <2:
    item= "a"+ str(i)
    List=[]
    List.append(item)
    print "item index is ", i, "item is ", item
    i+=1
  print List
```

The         `print "item index is ", i, "item is ", item`

For print List I am getting the output:

```
[a1]
```

I am trying to print the entire list.

What am I doing wrong, is it not adding the item to the list, or am I asking the see the whole list incorrectly?

*Please don't judge, I sometimes have difficulty grasping the most simple of things.*

Comment: It's worth noting that you should avoid `CapWords` for variable names - use `lowercase_with_underscores`. [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions) advises `CapWords` be reserved for classes.

Comment: Why is `List=[]` inside while loop ? It recreates the list on successive iterations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a **new list** every iteration in your loop. Move `List=[]` out of the loop.

```
List=[]
while i <2:
    item= "a"+ str(i)
    List.append(item)
    print "item index is ", i, "item is ", item
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also consider list comprehensions in order to avoid those issues, like this

```
my_list = ["a"+str(i) for i in range(2)] # xrange() for longer lists
print my_list # ['a0', 'a1']
```

Comment: You might want to [explain list comprehensions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw).